# How to add signals with atomic transaction?

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I have some api which will create User model and I have a post_save signal which will do some database update.

I want to apply `transaction.atomic` but is it required when using signal ? Does signals handle atomic transaction? If not how can I make it ?

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def some_signal(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    # some database transaction
    if instance:
        .....

  

class User(AbstractUser):
  ....

# api
 User.objects.create()
```

Comment: The signal will be fired within `.save()`, before exiting any `atomic` block you might have.